# For parallel translation $T_v$, does $T_{-v} = {T_v}^{-1}$ hold true?

Tags: vectors

As the title states, for parallel translation $T_v$, is $T_{-v} = {T_v}^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Please include your definition of $T_v$.

Comment: Your assumtion was correct it is $T_v(z) = z + v$

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? Can someone elaborate on what kind of additional context I should provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't respond to clarification request I'll assume $T_v(z)=z+v$ and things are in a vector space. Then $T_{-v}T_v(z)=T_{-v}(z+v)=(z+v)+(-v)=z.$

note fixed typo.